# What is causing these crashes in our ios/xmarin app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Our app has been working fine for weeks and then starting yesterday we are seeing all users getting app crashes (iphones and ipads). We pulled this one from a physical device

Any help or hints would be hugely appreciated

http://pastebin.com/1tkvmH2W

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report before people can help you.

Comment: If you use Xamarin.Insights or Raygun and then upload your dysm, you should be able to see where the error happened. Pretty much what @Kerni said.

Comment: This explains how to symbolicate: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/